# HTML Table CSS - Gap between TD's

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a newsletter and I've been informed that using tables for the layout is best practice.  The trouble I'm having is that a gap appears between my td's.  Each td has a background image so it's really obvious:

[image: Screenshot of gap between tds]

Here is my code, am I missing something obvious? I'm testing this in Firefox by the way:

```
  <table style = "margin: auto; width: 90%; max-width: 900px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;">
    <tr style = "height: 16px;">
      <td style = "width: 15px; background: url('http://yourhealthfoodstore.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/top_left.png') no-repeat center;"></td>
      <td style = "background: url('http://yourhealthfoodstore.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/top.png') repeat-x;"></td>
      <td style = "width: 15px; background: url('http://yourhealthfoodstore.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/top_right.png') no-repeat center;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `cellpadding` of the table to zero.

```
<table cellpadding="0" style = "margin: auto; width: 90%; max-width: 900px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;">
    <tr style = "height: 16px;">
      <td style = "width: 15px; background: url('http://yourhealthfoodstore.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/top_left.png') no-repeat center;"></td>
      <td style = "background: url('http://yourhealthfoodstore.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/top.png') repeat-x;"></td>
      <td style = "width: 15px; background: url('http://yourhealthfoodstore.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/top_right.png') no-repeat center;"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6oteoe96/

Comment: How did I miss this? Urgh... I'm a moron.  Thanks alot, will accept answer once the timer runs down.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the width of `td` to `13px`:

```html
<table style="margin: auto; width: 90%; max-width: 900px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;">
  <tr style="height: 16px;">
    <td style="width: 13px; background: url('http://yourhealthfoodstore.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/top_left.png') no-repeat center;"></td>
    <td style="background: url('http://yourhealthfoodstore.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/top.png') repeat-x;"></td>
    <td style="width: 13px; background: url('http://yourhealthfoodstore.co.uk/media/wysiwyg/top_right.png') no-repeat center;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```